# Should I capitalize 'western' when it anticipates 'culture'?

Tags: adjectives, capitalization, proper-nouns

The following sentences are from the transcription of a BBC podcast>

> In the **W**estern culture, we have got a bit of an uphill – I would say - struggle because pre-conceptions around eating insects are already sort of ingrained in society, so we already think before we've even tried them, they're going to taste disgusting or gross.

and

> Interestingly, it seems to be **w**estern cultures that don’t like eating insects – perhaps because it’s thought to be wrong or just disgusting, even if it’s not!'

The first one is capitalized but the second is not. That makes sense:t it's not an essay but a transcription. Is there a general rule regarding this case?

Comment: Yes, capitalize _Western culture_ that way. But don't say _**the** Western culture_. It's a general term like _Asian_, and there's not much you can say about it in the singular definite.

Comment: Likewise _Black_ and _White_, if you're in the capitalizing business.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. Some people capitalize more than others. There's no consensus.

Answer (score -1):

You should capitalize it. *Western* here is not a common adjective (like local), but is instead what is known as a *proper* adjective:

> Names of people, organizations, countries, towns etc are "proper nouns" and need to be capitalized in English. **Adjectives made from proper nouns are "proper adjectives" and also need to be capitalized.**
>
> ---
>
> [[English Club]](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/adjectives-proper.php)

Some more specific guidance:

> Capitalize such words as northern, southern, eastern, and western when they refer to the people in a region or to their political, social, or cultural activities. Do not capitalize these words when they merely indicate general location or refer to the geography or climate of the region.
>
> ---
>
> [[ProofreadNOW.com]](https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/30440/north-east-south-or-west-capitalize-or-not#:%7E:text=Capitalize%20such%20words%20as%20northern,or%20climate%20of%20the%20region.)

Comment: Those are just opinions, and not ones carrying much authority. Better to look at the leading style guides.

Comment: @StuartF I wonder where to find reliable answers